# Confirmation Box doesnt show and automatically delete

Tags: javascript, php, confirmation

HELP ME Please. I created a delete process wherein there i a confirm box to ask the user if he is sure or not.
 but the confirm box doesnt appear and automatically deletes the data and doesnt even redirect me. Help me plss!

I need to show the confirmation box ("are u sure") and if the input is true. it will delete the data and redirect to other page.

```
 <?php
 require_once('connect/connect.php');
 ?>
 <script>
 var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
 if (r == true)
 {
 alert(' item successfuly deleted!!');
 </script>
 <?php

 if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
$sql ='Select * FROM product where pid = '.$_GET['pid'];
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$pname = $data['pname'];
$pstock = $data['pstock'];
}
$sq3="INSERT INTO report VALUES('NULL','".$pname."', '" .$pstock. "', 'Item Deleted' )";
$qry3 = mysql_query($sq3);

$sql2 = 'DELETE FROM product where pid = '.$_GET['pid'];
$qry2 = mysql_query($sql2);
?>
<script>
 window.location.assign('products.php');    
 }
 </script>
 <script>
 else
 {
window.location.assign('products.php');
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed the closing brace `}` of `if` condition

```
 <script>
 var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
 if (r == true)
 {
 alert(' item successfuly deleted!!');
 }
 </script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3bba/)

Comment: Thank you sir! I didnt see that! You're awesome!

Comment: @Lemon:welcome..!! :) happy to help :) it would be nice if you accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try a short `if` statement

```
(r == true) ? alert('item successfuly deleted!!') : "" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the script tags before php tags start. Update the code as below:-

```
       <?php
       require_once('connect/connect.php');
       ?>
     <script>
    var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (r == true)
     {
       alert(' item successfuly deleted!!');

       <?php

       if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
       $sql ='Select * FROM product where pid = '.$_GET['pid'];
       $qry = mysql_query($sql);
       $data = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
       $pname = $data['pname'];
       $pstock = $data['pstock'];
       }
       $sq3="INSERT INTO report VALUES('NULL','".$pname."', '" .$pstock. "','Item Deleted' )";
        $qry3 = mysql_query($sq3);

        $sql2 = 'DELETE FROM product where pid = '.$_GET['pid'];
        $qry2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        ?>

         window.location.assign('products.php');    
        }

       else
       {
         window.location.assign('products.php');
        }
      </script>
```

Try this and confirm.

Comment: He is opening `<script>` tags for every js code. Its probably wrong but working for browsers. It's just bad syntax. Not the actual problem.

Comment: What I understood that he wants to run the PHP code within the if statement of script according to your answer the if statement of script will closed and data will deleted in every condition either user confirm it or not